# How to map Esc to an action in a Motif widget

Tags: c, keyboard-shortcuts, motif

This minimal example creates a Motif window with a push button widget.

```c
#include <Xm/PushB.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  XtAppContext app;
  Widget       toplevel, b;
  char         *translations="<Key>Escape: ArmAndActivate()\n\
                              <Key>a:      ArmAndActivate()";

  toplevel = XtVaOpenApplication(&app, "tl", NULL, 0, &argc, argv, NULL,
                                 sessionShellWidgetClass, NULL);
  
  b = XtVaCreateManagedWidget("button", xmPushButtonWidgetClass, toplevel, NULL);
  XtOverrideTranslations(b, XtParseTranslationTable(translations));

  XtRealizeWidget(toplevel);
  XtAppMainLoop(app);
  return(0);
}
```

Both <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> are mapped to the same action,
`ArmAndActivate`, but the widget only responds to <kbd>a</kbd> keypress, not to
<kbd>Esc</kbd>. **How can I make it respond to <kbd>Esc</kbd>?** Note that
`Escape` is indeed the correct keysym according to `xev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Escape` is the `osfCancel` Motif virtual binding](https://www.opengroup.org/infosrv/openmotif/R2.1.30/motif/lib/Xm/Transltns.c); in that sense it is
already "occupied". So use

```
<Key>osfCancel: ArmAndActivate()
```

The virtual bindings can be modified via the `~/.motifbind` file, see [The
Motif Programming Model](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/motif/vol6a/Vol6a_html/ch02.html) and [`man VirtualBindings`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/VirtualBindings.3.html).